# "The From phone number is not a valid" with a US number

Tags: java, sms, twilio

I'm new on Twilio and try to use JAVA API to send SMS. As I saw on other posts in SoF, I release my local first number and buy a US number to have a full features number. But I always have error message :

```
com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: The From phone number +14065302461 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.
```

my code is :

```
        SmsFactory messageFactory = mainAccount.getSmsFactory();
        List<NameValuePair> messageParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "<myphonenumber>"));
        messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+14065302461"));
        messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", message));

        try {
            messageFactory.create(messageParams);
            LOGGER.info("SMS sent");
        } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unexpected exception during SMS sending : ", e);
        }
```

My number is valid for SMS as you can see in that ps :

[image]

My code works with the magic number +15005550006.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is that a space in your number?

Answer (score 7):

OK understood the problem. I used my "Test AccountSID" instead of my "Live AccountSID". Perhaps a specific error message could be useful on this case.

Comment: [Full Test Credentials docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials)

Comment: How did you get the "Live AccountSid"?